# Merging partitions - Help for recovery

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

I have a 1TB external HDD. There were two partitions on this HDD. My first partition was a 60 GB partition and the second partition was a 871 GB partition. I did not need the data on the first partition, but I need the data on second partition. Last night I decided to merge these two partitions using gparted.

After I tried to merge these two partitions, gparted was merging these two partitions but it was taking a long time, 3 hours. but after about 2 hours the OS, Linux mint 15, stopped working and I could not do anything. I uploaded a video from this situation [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zign86ryeorwb28/20130613_011229.mp4). I could only move the mouse cursor.

But I think gparted was still doing its job, so I did not power off my laptop. I let the gparted do its job and I went to bed. When I woke up after 5 hours, the screen was completely black and I could not do anything and the external HDD was silent, as it was unmounted. After a shut down everything was ok But the OS, Linux mint 15, can not mount my external HDD. I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm4HY.png) error.

[image: Screenshot]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DV4D.png) is a shot of gparted from my external HDD after the merge. Right now there is only one 931GB partition which I can not access.

I prefer to some how recover the data which I had on the 871GB partition before merging. I have a backup from this data, but I prefer to recover it. I think if I could somehow know what happened that my system was not responding, I might find a better solution.

Should I recover the partition table? If I recover the partition table will I have my data?
How can I know what really happened that the system was frozen?

Edit 1: The 60GB partition was in ext4. The 871GB partition was in NTFS. Before merging these two, I deleted the 60 GB partition and reformatted it, most probably to NTFS but I am not sure and I can not remember.

Edit 2: The partition table for the HDD was GPT and not MBR.

Edit 3: Since the Testdisk command did not help, and it could not recover the partition table for the 871 GB drive. I did what the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm4HY.png) told me to do. 
I used the `chkdsk /f` command in windows to check my drive. I do not know why I was asked in the error to restart twice. But after the `chkdsk /f`, it took about 45 minutes, I shut down the windows system and rebooted but in the windows I could not access my drive. 
Then, I connected the drive to my linux system and I had all of my files in the correct order and correct name.

Now I have another problem. Although I can access all folders, but some files are corrupted. I can not see most .jpg files and most video and pdf files. I can play some mp3 files but the content is not related to the name of that mp3 file. I will try to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you recover the original partition table exactly as it was,
then you do have a chance of recovering your data.

This is because any data that was written 
when creating the 931GB partition has most likely only overwritten and destroyed
the first 60 GB partition, so you still have a chance of recovering the following
871GB partition.

If this doesn't work, then you will need to use recovery software that recovers
files, rather than partitions.
Re-establishing the old partition table will also help in this case,
concentrating your efforts on the disk area that used to contain the
871GB partition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you do not recommend me to run the chkdsk /f command on a windows? It was suggested by the error I received when I connect my HDD to my laptop.

Comment: NO! chkdsk can destroy the disk folder/file data and so render it unrecoverable. One thing I don't understand: Why chkdsk when your question is tagged "linux"?

Comment: I know chkdsk will destroy the data, but in the error as you can see, it says to use chkdsk /f and mention to use the /f parameter.  It is also VERY strange for me that in Linux it recommends me to use a Windows tool.

Comment: It probably badly analyzed the merged partition type as ntfs. Just ignore it.

Comment: I edited my post. The 871 GB partition was in NTFS, but I am not sure about the 60GB partition. 
I have created a clone of my damaged HDD and I am trying to recover the partition table using Testdisk.

Comment: A safer but much slower procedure would have been to delete the 60GB, move the 871GB to the top of the disk, then resize it to the full disk. I would also prefer handling ntfs using Windows.

Comment: I do not care if it takes a long time. If you check the photo from Gparted you will see that all I have right now is one 931 GB unallocated space. I had two partitions before merging, right now there is only one unallocated space.

Comment: How did it go with testdisk?

Comment: If you have access to a Windows computer, you can create a [UBCD4Win](http://www.ubcd4win.com/) rescue CD that has more tools, such as Recuva.

Comment: Testdisk only recovers the partition table for the first drive which was ext4. It does not recover the second partition.
I will try the UBCD4Win tonight. Thanks

Comment: You mean the first partition? If that partition is recovered (**and if** you have backup) you might simply try to re-create the second partition as the rest of the disk (without reformat of course).

Comment: I do not get your point. Yes, I have a backup. But I want to learn how these recovery tools really work and try to recover my data so that in future if some one had the same problem my situation could also help him.
Please check Edit3.

Comment: Returning the 871GB partition serves to : (1) maybe bring it back to life if none of it was modified on disk, (2) narrow the search field for the forensic tools that you wish to try. chkdsk only fixed the disk-tables of the 931GB merged partition, but as it is doubtful whether that partition was any good to start with, this may just confuse the forensic tools. It is questionable whether the files can be completely restored now.

Answer (score 0):

i would try to recover the data with the tools provided in deft linux or kali linux, booted in forensic mode they won't make any more changes to your drive. sleuthkit and ddrescue will probably be able to restore some/most/all data depending on your luck and state of the drive. it might also help in pinpointing what went wrong with te drive in the first place.